# PSR2 - multiline array indentation between key and value

Tags: php, psr-2

What is the correct way according to PSR2 for having spaces between keys and values of multiline array.

```
$result = [
    'key1'           => 'value1',
    'another_key'    => 'value2',
    'some_other_key' => 'value3'
];
```

vs

```
$result = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'another_key' => 'value2',
    'some_other_key' => 'value3'
];
```

It looks that the first one is more readable, but we are having extra spaces.

Answer (score 6):

According to:-[PSR-2 multiline array indentation missing](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues/1235)

> PSR-2 doesn't define how arrays should be indented, or if they should
>   even be indented at all, so PHPCS can't enforce any rules in this
>   area.
>
> When I have asked about arrays in other areas of the standard, the
>   response was to treat them like a single object, and ignore them. So
>   many PHPCS checks for PSR-2 actually skip right over arrays and don't
>   do any checking inside them either.
>
> So this isn't a bug, and it's also not something I can add to PHPCS
>   because PSR-2 doesn't define an array formatting standard.

***Note:-***

The same thing is stated in this thread too:- [Question on proper Array syntax](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/php-fig-cs/Go9HA6qhzaU)

> There's no correct answer, beacuse the PSR is silent on the matter,
>   but I think your assumption is reasonable. It's certainly my practice.

***Even if you check this thread:-*** [Coding Style Guide Additions](https://github.com/php-fig-rectified/fig-rectified-standards/blob/master/PSR-2-R-coding-style-guide-additions.md#multi-line-arrays)

It only states about adding `,` not about anything regarding adding spaces.

> Arrays that span across multiple lines can have a trailing comma to
>   make sure that adding new rows does not change the previous row, as
>   well.